# Indeterminate spinner not the same size as id.menu_refresh?

Tags: android

I'm trying to transition over to ActionBar. I need an indeterminate spinner as well as a refresh button. If I use Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS with my activity, I will get an indeterminate spinner ok on ICS, but it's way bigger than the refresh asset. Is there any way to make it smaller? Below is a screenshot of what it looks like on a galaxy nexus:

[image: Spinner and Refresh Button]

Also it's kind of weird to have two progress spinners up there at once. I was hoping that if you had a refresh button visible, calling setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility() would just reuse the id.menu_refresh one. Argh.

Thanks

Comment: I worked around this by using ActionBar.setCustomView() and supplying a progress spinner when the menu doesn't happen to have a menu_refresh item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using ActionBar.setCustomView() and supplying a progress spinner when the menu doesn't happen to have a menu_refresh item.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the indeterminate progress indicator by adding `<item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Widget.ProgressBar</item>` to your `ActionBar`'s style where your supplied style (`@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large`) is a progress bar style such as

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Large" parent="@style/Widget">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_large</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">3500</item>
</style>
```

and the `android:indeterminateDrawable` (`@drawable/progress_large` in this case) is something like

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_black_76"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```